# How to change the background color of sap.m.Button?

Tags: css, user-experience, sapui5

I have some buttons that I would like to change the color of but not sure how to do it. 
code:

```
<Button id="evalPriceButton" text="Evaluate Price" icon="sap-icon://sales-order" type="Accept" press="onPricePress" />
```

As shown in my code I'm using one of the default types provided by sap, but I cannot set my own color. I'm also using one of the icons provided in their library which shows different buttons with different colors, but they don't specify how to change those colors. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/iconExplorer.html

I want it to look like the green one.
Is it fully necessary to override the css in order to change the look of the button?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "like the green one", you mean one of the colors of those rotating divs in the Icon Explorer. Unfortunately, those colors come from custom CSS classes. They are not specified in the documentation. So yes, you will have to:

- Use the [UI Theme Designer](https://help.sap.com/viewer/09f6818d8e064537973102d6289e2aca)
- Write [your own CSS class](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796) although it is **not recommended** for Fiori apps

  > SAP Fiori launchpad apps should not override styles.

You can read more about the theming here: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/497c27a8ee26426faacd2b8a1751794a

Comment: I don't know why the link it's not coming up as it should, it keeps pointing to the main page rather than the specific item I want to show. Anyway, no I don't mean the rotating divs. If you open one of the items you would see the buttons at the bottom (red and green) which it's what I want. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: @polaris: I see. Those "red" and "green" colors are semantic colors coming from properties like `type` in [sap.m.Button](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ButtonType.html). If the type is "Accept", the button will set its background color to green (meaning positive).

Comment: you are right. I already have that property set as you can see in my code but for some reason it's not working on my application It doesn't make the buttons fully red/green, only the edge. Not sure why this is happening. I need to look into this

Comment: @polaris: So that's the problem. Now I understand. It's theme-dependent. If you set your theme in `sap_bluecrystal` instead of `sap_belize` (in your index.html), you will see that your button will turn green completely. Change it back to one of the belize themes, then the button will look differently. The theme used in the Icon Explorer is still **`sap_bluecrystal`** which [is deprecated](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/a87ca843bcee469f82a9072927a7dcdb.html). So in the end, you will have to use either your own CSS classes or the UI Theme Designer to change this behavior.